# Translating recursivity to assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to translate a C++ recursive code in assembly. I work in the 32-bits mode.

Here's the C++ code.

```
1 extern "C" void output (unsigned);
2 extern "C" void parcours (unsigned[], unsigned, unsigned = 0);
3
4 void parcours (unsigned v[], unsigned n, unsigned k) {
5     while (k < n) {
6         output(v[k]);
7         parcours(v, n, 2*k+1);
8         k = 2*k+2;
9     }
10 }
```

And here's my attempt at translating it. I am struggling with translating a recursive C++ (or any other high-level language) into assembly. I would greatly appreciate if you could correct this code and point out my mistakes.

```
%include "io.inc"

section .text
global start

start:    
    mov edi, [ebp+8]    ;address of the first element of the array
    mov eax, [ebp+12]   ;n
    mov edx, [ebp+16]   ;k

parcours:
    enter 0,0           ;stack frame creation
    push edx            ;we save k before the modification

    shl edx,1
    add edx,1 ;2*k+1


loop:
    cmp edx,eax
    jb endloop          ;if k < n

    push [edi+edx]      ;we push for the output
    call output
    pop ebx

    call parcours
    shl edx,1           ;2*k
    add edx,2           ;2*k+2
    jmp loop

endloop:
    pop edx
    leave               ;stack frame destruction
    ret
```

Comment: There's no difference in translating non-recursive and recursive C++ into assembly, from the CPU point of view it would be actually quite difficult to detect recursivity reliably in every possible source, nor it does affect the produced assembly in any way. The compiler will just compile it as any other function, following the configured calling convention. You can use C++ compiler to check what compiler would do (but it may be tricky to set reasonable amount of optimization to get some nice assembly). Your current assembly probably clutters values in registers, which should be preserved.

Comment: Actually you don't use `ebx` for anything, just as scratch, but if I guess your calling convention correctly, you should save it (or avoid cluttering it completely). And `eax, edx` will probably not survive `call output`. Otherwise that code looks quite good to me, try it in debugger to see yourself, if it works as expected (use some arguments which will do just no-recursion, then depth=1, then depth=2+).

Comment: Just follow a compiler calling convention and it will just work, no reason to design for recursive vs not recursive, they can be the same code.

Comment: The point is that I want to exercise myself and understand correctly how it works. @Ped7g I am going to try what you said.

Comment: `enter 0,0` - ok but I suggest `push ebp \ mov ebp, esp` (which is also what you will see compilers do if they use a frame pointer)

Comment: @harold isn't it the same?

Comment: One more note, your code is more toward "efficient" way, I still assume calling convention like "cdecl"/similar, where arguments should be passed through stack, while you use pass-by-register values to save stack, which is a bit more tricky to get right, and breaks ABI rules, so you will be not able to easily call your function from C/C++ or other modules, which are not aware of your custom calling arguments in registers. This is fast+tricky approach, so you should check *also* C/C++ version by compiler, which will follow the calling convention completely and use stack for all arguments.

Comment: about `enter`.. yes, it's the same, but the `push + mov` executes faster on modern x86 CPUs, `enter` never really picked up in compilers (= not optimized heavily by CPU vendors).

Comment: So, I tried the code, calling the function output, but it shows me funny alot of funny values before ending with a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

It just so happens that there are tools designed specifically for the purpose of translating C++ code into assembly. Such tools are known as "compilers", and this is literally their main purpose.

What you do is run the C++ code through a compiler, along with the appropriate flag that causes it to give you the intermediate assembly-language representation. In Gnu-style compilers, like GCC and Clang, that would be `-S` (`-fverbose-asm` is also helpful). For Microsoft compilers, the option is [`/FA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6.aspx).

Alternatively, you can compile the code and then use a tool like `objdump` (Gnu) or `dumpbin` (MS) to display an assembly listing of the object code. (If you compile with debug symbols, this has the nice effect of interleaving the corresponding C++ statements within the assembly instructions, at least to the best of the compiler's ability, since there is not necessarily a 1-to-1 mapping, not to mention the issue of instruction reordering for optimization purposes).

Either has the same effect. You turn this:

```
 extern "C" void output (unsigned);
 extern "C" void parcours (unsigned[], unsigned, unsigned = 0);

 void parcours (unsigned v[], unsigned n, unsigned k) {
     while (k < n) {
         output(v[k]);
         parcours(v, n, 2*k+1);
         k = 2*k+2;
     }
 }
```

into this:

```
parcours:
        push    edi
        push    esi
        push    ebx
        mov     esi, DWORD PTR [esp+20]
        mov     ebx, DWORD PTR [esp+24]
        mov     edi, DWORD PTR [esp+16]
        cmp     ebx, esi
        jnb     .L1
.L3:
        sub     esp, 12
        push    DWORD PTR [edi+ebx*4]
        add     ebx, ebx
        call    output
        lea     eax, [ebx+1]
        add     esp, 12
        add     ebx, 2
        push    eax
        push    esi
        push    edi
        call    parcours
        add     esp, 16
        cmp     esi, ebx
        ja      .L3
.L1:
        pop     ebx
        pop     esi
        pop     edi
        ret
```

That's the assembly language code that an optimizing compiler would generate for your `parcours` function. From here, you need to do two things:

1. Go through the code and make sure you understand what each instruction does, why the compiler emitted it, and how the function works as a whole. Trace through the code as if you were a computer executing it, making sure you understand it.
2. Write a wrapper around it that includes the things typically required by an assembler, like `section .text` and an entry point.

Notice that the recursion is simply achieved by calling the `parcours` function again from within the `parcours` function. The only difference between C++ and assembly here is that C++ uses `parcours(v, n, 2*k+1);`, while assembly uses a series of `push` instructions (for the parameters) followed by `call parcours`.

What's different about this code compared to what you've written?

Well, for starters, as discussed in the comments, it follows a standard *calling convention*, where non-volatile registers are preserved at the top (with a series of `push` instructions) and restored at the bottom (with a corresponding series of `pop` instructions). Parameters are passed in a standard way, from right-to-left, on the stack.

Also, optimizing compilers are (not surprisingly) better at generating optimal sequences of code than you are. In particular, they know it is slow to use `enter` and `leave` to create/destroy stack frames, so instead they manipulate the stack pointer (`esp`) directly, and do it only when/where required. As another example, they know that `shl reg, 1` is equivalent to `add reg, reg`, but the latter is faster. And they know cute little tricks like `lea eax, [ebx+1]` being an efficient way to add 1 to the value of `ebx` while storing the result in `eax` without modifying `ebx`.

Most importantly, though, they have book-keeping algorithms that keep the stack correctly balanced while doing recursive function calls, something that you weren't able to do correctly in your attempt, which is what caused the segmentation fault.

I'll leave you to do a detailed, line-by-line comparison of your attempt to what a C++ compiler generates. This is a very effective way to learn how to write assembly code. As would have been stepping through your code with a debugger to see precisely where it went off the rails. It's not too late to try that now, and compare the results to this correct code.

Comment: I don't understand quite well why we substract 12 of esp, and then later we add 16 after the call.

Comment: `push`ing a 32-bit register is equivalent to subtracting 4 bytes from the stack pointer. So, when you have `sub esp, 12` followed by `push DWORD …`, you have to clean the stack by `add`ing 16 bytes to `esp`. I mean, you could have done `pop reg`+`add esp, 12`, but that would have the disadvantages of (1) clobbering a register and (2) being more instructions than necessary, so compilers just do a single `add esp, 16`. @carlfou